# Whether a table which stores data about single item should grow horizontally or vertically?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-attribute-value

Suppose I have a `user` table that stores the data of single user.

Initially we know nothing about the user, so there is nothing in the table(may be only single column like `id` which is of no use in this case ).

We do not know what are the details we are going to have about the user and we do not know in which order we are getting the details. Details about user will be obtained gradually in any order.

My question is ,For Example, if I got the name of user, how should I enter it in the table?

**I have two options**

**1) Alter the table structure and add a column called username and store the data there. For all new detail, this process is repeated. So all data will be in one row.**

**2)Alter the table structure and add to columns `key` and `value`. Give `name` as a `key` and store the name of user as its `value`. Thus for each detail about the user,a new row is inserted as key value pairs.**

First method makes the table grow horizontally.
Second one make it grow vertically.

which one is good on the basis of good design methods  and ease of querying?

Comment: A properly designed table with well-defined columns is usually the best approach.  There are situations where key/value pairs are useful, but it is best to define the table structure *before* putting data into it.

Comment: The answer is (as for almost all design related questions), that it depends on the exact circumstances. It is pretty difficult to provide a general guidance.

Comment: You may not be doing your question justice by using "user" as an example here, as everyone's first reaction is going to be "of course you know what the attributes are for a user". If you have a case in which you need to store unknown attributes that can vary by entity then please say so -- questions generally work better when you try to describe the problem that you're looking for a solution to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But what would you suggest if the number of user attributes simply isn't know at the time the database is launched?

Comment: @GordonLinoff OK.. But my case I dont know what are the data that I am gonna have from user. So I cant make columns earlier

Comment: @jophabHave you looked into MySQL-specific solutions other than these two options? In PostgreSQL I'd be thinking about JSONB or hstore data types, for example.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I am sorry about that.. you are right.. Different users can have different attributes

Comment: @jophab If the different rows can definitely have different attributes, and it's possible that the number of attributes is more than a handful, then I think you should be looking either at relational or hstore key-value, or JSON, or not a relational database at all (unless you have to join with other data in the relational database).

Comment: @DavidAldridge There wont be details about multiple users in the user table. it will contain details about a single user. There will be different tables for different users.

Comment: @jophab If you are using relation dbs each entity (here user) should be a row if you have a different table per user then just dump in flat files as XML or json a file per user.  For the key value anti patten see Entity-attribute-Value

Comment: @jophab"There will be different tables for different users" -- now there's a red flag.

Comment: @Mark :+1 I will try it

Comment: @DavidAldridge Actually these tables will be in different devices. Each device storing data of its user.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect the metadata associated with a user could become arbitrarily large, then adding columns probably isn't the best approach.  So this would leave your suggestion to simply add key/value pairs for each new feature associated with a user.  There is a third option, which I don't like for so many reasons, which would be to store JSON containing key/value pairs in a single column of the user table.  We currently use this approach sporadically, but we handle the JSON manipulation in our Java app layer, which is relatively painless.  From a pure database point of view, this isn't so desirable.

So I would vote for your second option of using key/value pairs, because it would scale well.  Note that this does not imply that your user table would only have a single column.  You might know that a certain number of user attributes will always be there, e.g. username, hashed password, etc., and these columns could be added at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what others have already said, you could use a hybrid approach as well.  If there are any predefined columns (username, firstname, lastname, password, etc.), you could put those in a table with defined fields, and then link a second table with key/value pairs for additional data.

Comment: Thank you @philipxt